How to enable accentuation in my code in CLion?
I'm trying to allow accentuation in my code, specifically within the printf() function. I've used setlocale() and tried passing various different parameters to it, but none worked. I'm using CLion, and both global and project settings are configured for UTF-8, seemingly using cmake.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "cubo.h"

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    double lado = 5.5;
    CUBO cubo = inicializa_cubo(lado);
    printf("PROPRIEDADES DO CUBO\n");
    printf("Lado do cubo: %lf\n", lado_cubo(cubo));
    printf("Área do cubo: %lf\n", area_cubo(cubo));
    printf("Volume do cubo: %lf\n\n", volume_cubo(cubo));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
UPDATE
I was able to "solve" the problem by setting these configurations and adapting the code as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cubo.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

int main() {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);  // Muda a Code Page de saída do Windows para UTF-8
        SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);  // Muda a Code Page de entrada do Windows para UTF-8
    #endif
    double lado = 5.5;
    CUBO cubo = inicializa_cubo(lado);
    printf("PROPRIEDADES DO CUBO\n");
    printf("Lado do cubo: %lf\n", lado_cubo(cubo));
    printf("Área do cubo: %lf\n", area_cubo(cubo));
    printf("Volume do cubo: %lf\n\n", volume_cubo(cubo));
    #ifdef _WIN32
        system("pause");
    #elif __linux__
        printf("Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .");
        getchar();
    #endif
    return 0; }




Doesn't work for me either until I also set the output code page.  For windows that's SetConsoleOutputCP.  I'm hoping there is an equivalent API for the OS/platform you are using.

@gregspears I've been researching a lot about this and trying to understand what should be done... If I try to change everything from the IDE to UTF-8 and use setlocale for my language and UTF-8 (something like setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt-BR.UTF-8")), it doesn't work. And if I try to change the IDE settings to ISO-8859-1 and use setlocale only for my language (something like setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt-BR")), it works, but I don't understand why, since UTF-8 should include accents from my country.

What are your OS and compiler?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I'm using Windows 10 and GCC. I've added an image of the encoding settings in CLion.

Your solution is OK.
